# Refresh a table with jQuery/Ajax every 5 seconds

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I have a table pulling information from a database and I was wondering how I could make it refresh its information without reloading the whole page.

Comment: The answer is in the question : add a script reloading the table data using AJAX every 5 seconds. Google for the setTimeout JavaScript function.

Comment: How do you have your backend setup? Are you planning on calling a script such as `getData.php?startID=1&endID=10` type of thing?

Answer (score 39):

You'll need a `getTable.php` page that displays your table, and nothing else: no headers, footers, etc.

**PHP (getTable.php) - this can be any server side code (asp, html, etc..)**

```
<?php
    echo '<table><tr><td>TEST</td></tr></table>';
?>
```

Then, in your JS, you can easily refresh the table by using the `load()` method:

**HTML**

```
<div id="tableHolder"></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tableHolder').load('getTable.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, even usable when using ASP (as it was my case)

Comment: Good reply.  To help clarify, 1000 ms = 1 second.  So: setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000); -- refreshes table every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Dutchie432 How do i set this up with a asp table? i don't use php.

Comment: @Pomster the code is exactly the same, but instead of calling for `getTable.php` you just call `getTable.asp` or whatever your ASP page is called. You just need to have that ASP page create your table.

Comment: Worth mentioning (for noobs like me) that you need to import jQuery to your html file in the <HEAD> e.g. 
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>`
Wasted a good 10 minutes on this one!

Comment: Fair enough. The poster added a jQuery tag to the question, so I answered based on the assumption that it was already included.

Answer (score 8):

Use ajax, following example is in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var prevAjaxReturned = true;
    var xhr = null;

    setInterval(function() {
        if( prevAjaxReturned ) {
            prevAjaxReturned = false;
        } else if( xhr ) {
            xhr.abort( );
        }

        xhr = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: "v1="+v1+"&v2="+v2,
            url: "location/of/server/script.php",
            success: function(html) {
                 // html is a string of all output of the server script.
                $("#element").html(html);
                prevAjaxReturned = true;
           }

        });

    }, 5000);
});
```

The success function assumes that your server script outputs the html that you want to replace in the element with id 'element'.

Comment: The "problem" with this solution is that it does not start the timer once the load is done. In other words, if your request takes more than 5 seconds to return, you will have overlapping ajax requests. I suggest using .abort() before initiating a new call.

Comment: @Dutchie correct. I have updated the answer to reflect a more robust solution.  OP and others interested should read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/446626/697370 for limitations on `abort`

Comment: Alternatively, you can use my answer below, which starts the auto-timer once the ajax is finished.

Answer (score 6):

You should have a page that return the information and pull data using Ajax / jQuery.

```
<div class="result"></div>

setInterval(function() {

    $.get('table.php', function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data);
    });

}, 5000);
```

Comment: The "problem" with this solution is that it does not start the timer once the load is done. In other words, if your request takes more than 5 seconds to return, you will have overlapping ajax requests. I suggest using `.abort()` before initiating a new call.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option for you to use.  This solution is using an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) which is preferred over setInterval.  You can read more about IIFE at the link above.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var $results = $('#results'),
    loadInterval = 5000;
(function loader() {
    $.get('script.php', function(html){
            $results.hide(200, function() {
                $results.empty();
                $results.html(html);
                $results.show(200, function() {
                    setTimeout(loader, loadInterval);
                });
            });
    });
})();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, but i dont actually know the function to refresh a table.

Comment: @Etienne Dupuis I think gives a good example of how to get the data.

Comment: @Etienne Dupuis Sorry, I'm leaning towards watchers answer.  I like the setInterval() verse setTimeout();  I didn't know about this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function(){

      jqueryFunction(Args);

},100);
```

will work...

100 = 100 milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

The following works with JQuery Datatables 1.10

```
`var tableName;
//Set AJAX Refresh interval.
$(function() {
    setReloadInterval(10);  //Refresh every 10 seconds. 
}

//Because function takes seconds we * 1000 to convert seconds to milliseconds.
function setReloadInterval(reloadTime) {
    if(reloadTime > 0)
        internalId = setInterval("reloadTable()", (reloadTime * 1000);
}

//Auto Refresh JQuery DataTable 
function reloadTable() {
    tableName.ajax.reload();
}

//Table defined...
$(document).ready(function () {
    tableName = $('#tableName').DataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "/someUrl",
});`
```