# How to refresh a div every 5 seconds

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making a chat room for my website. I am using php and mysql to display and store the messages. I am trying to use Jquery and AJAX to refresh the page every 5 seconds. I have never used Jquery or AJAX before. Here is my Jquery and AJAX code.

```
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

                    <script type="text/javascript">                             
                    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                    function(){
                    $('#message_display').load('show_messages_public.php');
                            }, 5000);
                    </script>
```

In the 'show_messages_public.php' page I have a function called 'show_messages()' how would I call this function from the AJAX and Jquery?

```
<?php
session_start();

function show_messages()
{
$mysql_host = "******";
$mysql_database = "*******";
$mysql_user = "*****";
$mysql_password = "*****";

$link= mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);

if (!$link) {
    die('could not connect:' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected= mysql_select_db($mysql_database);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('can\'t use' . $mysql_database . ':' . mysql_error());
}

$query= "SELECT * FROM public_chat ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 2";
$result= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row= mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
    echo '<br/><font color="black">' .$row['time'] . "<br>" . '<b><big>' . '<font color="black">' . $row['user'] . ':' . '</big></b>' . " <br> " . $row['message'] .'</font>'; 
    echo "<br/><hr width=\"95%\"<br/>"/*"<hr width=\"90%\">"*/;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Read up on `setTimeout` function to do something every X (milli)seconds

Comment: @Worm and how does the `show_messages_public.php` code look like post it aswell if u may

Comment: Please refer to a similar post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681380/refresh-a-table-with-jquery-ajax-ever-5-seconds][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681380/refresh-a-table-with-jquery-ajax-ever-5-seconds

Comment: @Breezer I added my PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

When you have more than one function inside your php file you can do this:

You can POST parameters with the load function from jquery. So you can try this:

```
$('#message_display').load('show_messages_public.php', {showmsg: 'public'});
```

Inside your php:

```
switch($_POST['showmsg']) {
    case 'public':
        show_messages();
        break;
}
```

If you don't have more than one function, just call the code without a function:

```
<?php
session_start();

$mysql_host = "******";
$mysql_database = "*******";
$mysql_user = "*****";
$mysql_password = "*****";

$link= mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);

if (!$link) {
    die('could not connect:' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected= mysql_select_db($mysql_database);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('can\'t use' . $mysql_database . ':' . mysql_error());
}

$query= "SELECT * FROM public_chat ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 2";
$result= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row= mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
    echo '<br/><font color="black">' .$row['time'] . "<br>" . '<b><big>' . '<font color="black">' . $row['user'] . ':' . '</big></b>' . " <br> " . $row['message'] .'</font>'; 
    echo "<br/><hr width=\"95%\"<br/>"/*"<hr width=\"90%\">"*/;
}
?>
```

Comment: I used the function in my html page to show the messages. In my html page I have something like         <div id="message_display">      <?php
show_messages();
?>
</div> So I need the function.

Comment: than try way 1 (with the post)

Comment: hmm and if you try to use `if(isset($_POST)) show_messages();` instead of the switch (outside the function). Than it should call the function when post is set.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

You need to put all of the flow control into your host web page, as you can't load external program flow from AJAX.

---

After your update, it looks like you're trying to call into PHP, not JavaScript.

The answer is simple:  The idea is that your page will render the data, so just put show_messages() at the end of the page -- or, really.. just remove the function wrapper entirely.

Answer (score 0):

> In the 'show_messages_public.php' page I have a function called 'show_messages()' how would I call this function from the AJAX and Jquery?

You wouldn't. Your PHP page should return data based on the parameteres passed via either a GET or POST request. For example, you could send in the following parameters:

- startInt = 1
- repeatTimes = 5
- incrementIncrease = 3

Like this:

```
 $('#message_display').load('show_messages_public.php?startInt=1&repeatTimes=5&incrementIncrease=3');
```

And then in your PHP, you could return the result as plain text like this:

```
<?
    var startInt = $_GET['startInt'];
    var repeatTimes = $_GET['repeatTimes'];
    var incrementIncrease = $_GET['incrementIncrease'];

    var str = "";
    for (var i = startInt; i < repeatTimes * incrementIncrease + startInt; i += incrementIncrease) {
         str .= i."|";
    }

    echo str;
?>
```

This would return the following:

> 1|4|7|10|13|16|

I know that doesn't actually solve your problem, but it seems you need to learn the basics of AJAX.

---

**To Actually Solve Your Problem:**

You could try this code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#message_display').load('show_messages_public.php?callfunc=true');
}, 5000);
```

And then in your PHP:

```
 if ($_GET['callfunc'] == "true")
     show_messages();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling a function through AJAX but just executing remote address (URL) and then working with the response