# Auto refresh MySQL Query results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these DIVS which run PHP functions and return results. How can i make the returned results automatically refresh every X seconds without refreshing the whole page.

I just want to re-run the PHP/MySQL queries that are in the functions

```
<div class="container">

<div class="box"><h2>Callers Waiting</h2><?php echo CallersWaiting($queue_name, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour'))); ?></div>

<div class="box"><h2>Average Hold Time</h2><?php echo AverageHoldTime($queue_name, $date); ?></div>

<div class="box"><h2>Longest Wait Time</h2><?php echo LongestWaitTime($queue_name, $date); ?></div>

<div class="box"><h2>Shortest Wait Time</h2><?php echo ShortestWaitTime($queue_name, $date); ?></div>

</div>
```

UPDATE:

I have used this code:

```
<div class="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('.container').load('data.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 2000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

then all my divs and PHP Functions run on a page called data.php but nothing is showing on my index.php page

Comment: AJAX is what you need.  You can't do this purely with PHP, as PHP runs server-side.

Comment: do you have an example in ajax? I have only ever used PHP & HTML

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681380/refresh-a-table-with-jquery-ajax-every-5-seconds

Comment: if i use that code i will have to have a separate page for each function

Comment: No you wouldn't. You'd just need one page that calculates all of the values and sends them back (either already in the desired HTML, or in a format like JSON that you can parse and put the pieces where they go).

Comment: check my update - what i have tried

Comment: use [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://www.yourdomain.com/yoursite.html">
```

regresh page after 5 sec and if you need js i can send it too

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
```

For ajax you need a page that return all you data in Json or xml form.

then you need to make $.POST or $.GET or $AJAX request to that page and then parse it and then update your html elements.

example

http://danielnouri.org/notes/2011/03/13/an-ajax-page-update-mini-tutorial/

Comment: i don't want to refresh the whole page

Comment: true that is right way to do it. how ever it will be complicated. You need ajax or jquery

Comment: do you have an example?

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('.container').load('data.php');
}, 2000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
});
// ]]></script>

<div class="container">Loading data ...</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to refresh a page when clicking on a div, you can use [AJAX Poll](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_poll.asp), but if you want to update the element every specific period, your code must be like so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'data.php',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#your-element-id").html(data.your_data);
            },
            error: function (ERROR) {
                console.log(ERROR);
            }
        });
    }, 2000); // trigger this function every 2 sec.
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that data.php is something like this:

```
//require whatever you need for the functions to operate properly

$queue_name = $_POST["queue_name"]; //assuming that you have a queue_name post parameter

<div class="box"><h2>Callers Waiting</h2><?php echo CallersWaiting($queue_name, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour'))); ?></div>

<div class="box"><h2>Average Hold Time</h2><?php echo AverageHoldTime($queue_name, $date); ?></div>

<div class="box"><h2>Longest Wait Time</h2><?php echo LongestWaitTime($queue_name, $date); ?></div>

<div class="box"><h2>Shortest Wait Time</h2><?php echo ShortestWaitTime($queue_name, $date); ?></div>
```

You could send an AJAX request like this:

```
$.post('data.php', { queue_name: "<?php echo $queue_name ?>"}, 
    function(data){
         $(".container").html(returnedData);
}).fail(function(){
      console.log("error");
});
```

Of course, if data.php does other things, then you may need to check whether it's POST or not or implement a new PHP file for your POST requests.