# update a mysql database without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, database

I have a webpage (php) that fetches data from mysql as in the figure

[image: The webPage that show MySQL table]
I managed to make it refresh but it reloads the whole page. But I just want it to refresh the database every second without reloading the whole page or a button. I understand that I have to use AJAX and JQuery, but I didn't understand how. Here is my php code for the two php files `fetch.php` and `index.php`.

If any body knows how that would be done I much appreciate it!

```js
<?php


//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sid", "", "python");
$columns = array('timestamp', 'message', 'topic', 'start', 'End');

$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ";

if($_POST["is_date_search"] == "yes")
{
 $query .= 'timestamp BETWEEN "'.$_POST["start_date"].'" AND "'.$_POST["end_date"].'" AND ';
}

if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
 $query .= '
  (message LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
  OR topic LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%")
 ';
}

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$columns[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' 
 ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY timestamp DESC ';
}

$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, $query));

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query . $query1);

$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = $row["timestamp"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["topic"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["message"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["start"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["End"];
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function get_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM messages";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}

$output = array(
 "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
 "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
 "data"    => $data
);


echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
 <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">  -->
  <title> Automated System</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

 

  <style>
   body
   {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
   }
   .box
   {
    width:1270px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-top:25px;
   }
  </style>
  

 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="container box">
   <h1 align="center"> Automated System</h1>   
      <br />  
                <form method="post" action="export.php" align="center">  
                     <input type="submit" name="export" value="CSV Export" class="btn btn-success" />  
                </form>  
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <br />
    <div class="row">
     <div class="input-daterange">
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" class="form-control" />
      </div>      
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="button" name="search" id="search" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table id="order_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Error Reported </th>
       <th>Board No.</th>
       <th>Status</th>
       <th>Repairing Started</th>
       <th>Finished Repairing</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </body>
</html>



<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
  todayBtn:'linked',
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
  autoclose: true
 });

 fetch_data('no');

 function fetch_data(is_date_search, start_date='', end_date='')
 {
  var dataTable = $('#order_data').DataTable({
   "processing" : true,
   "serverSide" : true,
   "order" : [],
   "ajax" : {
    url:"fetch.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{
     is_date_search:is_date_search, start_date:start_date, end_date:end_date
    }
   }
  });
 }

 $('#search').click(function(){
  var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
  var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
  if(start_date != '' && end_date !='')
  {
   $('#order_data').DataTable().destroy();
   fetch_data('yes', start_date, end_date);
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Both Date is Required");
  }
 }); 
 
});
</script>
```

Comment: On the margin: You have terrible SQL injections

Comment: You're right that Ajax should be used, there are many tutorials for this if you just Google around a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh a table with jQuery/Ajax every 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681380/refresh-a-table-with-jquery-ajax-every-5-seconds)

Comment: Tolis: i tried to replicate a lot of tutorials , but something messing
tima : i will try to give it another shot 
i know that the problem is in the fetch.php 
i cant get update from it . it just have to be just echo (table) from the comments